# Wordpress Multisite woocommerce with Stripe Payments: Do I need a unique webhook for each store

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, webhooks, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite woocommerce setup with Stripe Payments

Do I need to add a unique webhook for each store?

For example

- xyz.com  **webhook** xyz.com/?wc-api=wc_stripe
- xyz.com/uk  **webhook** xyz.com/uk/?wc-api=wc_stripe
- xyz.com/ca  **webhook** xyz.com/ca/?wc-api=wc_stripe
- xyz.com/dk  **webhook** xyz.com/dk/?wc-api=wc_stripe

Or will one webhook **xyz.com/?wc-api=wc_stripe** be used for all subsites?

And if it is a unique webhook for each subsite what happens if I have more than 16 stores as Stripe only allows 16 webhooks.

Comment: In the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/account/multiple-accounts) it is mentioned _"You must use separate Stripe accounts for projects, websites, or businesses that operate independently from one another."_ . That's because Stripe would need to separate each project from a risk / aggregation perspective. The preferred scenario is, to run Stripe in one site, if you have a multisite network, you will need one Stripe account, Stripe Keys, and one Stripe configuration for each site [source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-compatibility-124/).

Comment: Just to be sure. Is your website translated/multilingual using a plugin or multisite in the sense that you use the same installation to run several independent sites?

Comment: One wordpress installation with several independent sites. So there is a separate woocommerce install for each subsite.